# operate a custom loop inside ddply

Tags: r, for-loop, plyr, conditional-statements

My data set has about 54,000 rows. I want to set a value (First_Pass) to either T or F depending upon both a value in another column and also whether or not that other column's value has been seen before. I have a for loop that does exactly what I need it to do. However, that loop is only for a subset of the data. I need that same for loop to be run individually for different subsets based upon factor levels.

This seems like the perfect case for the plyr functions as I want to split the data into subsets, apply a function (my for loop) and then rejoin the data. However, I cannot get it to work. First, I give a sample of the df, called char.data.

```
     session_id list Sent_Order Sentence_ID Cond1 Cond2 Q_ID   Was_y CI CI_Delta character tsle tsoc Direct
5139          2    b          9          25    rc    su   25 correct  1        0         T  995   56      R
5140          2    b          9          25    rc    su   25 correct  2        1         h   56   56      R
5141          2    b          9          25    rc    su   25 correct  3        1         e   56   56      R
5142          2    b          9          25    rc    su   25 correct  4        1             56   37      R
```

There is some clutter in there. The key columns are session_id, Sentence_ID, CI, and CI_Delta.

I then initialise a column called First_Pass to "F"

char.data$First_Pass <- "F"

I want to now calculate when First_Pass is actually "T" for each combination of session_id and Sentence_ID. I created a toy set, which is just one subset to work out the overall logic. Here's the code of a for loop that gives me just what I want for the toy data.

```
char.data.toy$First_Pass <- "F"
l <-c(200)
for (i in 1:nrow(char.data.toy)) {
  if(char.data.toy[i,]$CI_Delta >= 0 & char.data.toy[i,]$CI %nin% l){
    char.data.toy[i,]$First_Pass <- "T"
    l <- c(l,char.data.toy[i,]$CI)}
}
```

I now want to take this loop and run it for every session_id and Sentence_ID subset. I've created a function called set_fp and then called it inside ddply. Here is that code:

```
#define function
set_fp <- function (df){

  l <- 200
  for (i in 1:nrow(df)) {
    if(df[i,]$CI_Delta >= 0 & df[i,]$CI %nin% l){
      df[i,]$First_Pass <- "T"
      l <- c(l,df[i,]$CI)}
    else df[i,]$First_Pass <- "F"
    return(df)
  }

}

char.data.fp <- ddply(char.data,c("session_id","Sentence_ID"),function(df)set_fp(df))
```

Unfortunately, this is not quite right. For a long time, I was getting all "F" values for First_Pass. Now I'm getting 24 T values, when it should be many more, so I suspect, it's only keeping the last subset or something similar. Help?

Comment: I may have resolved this. I moved the return outside of the for loop and now it's returning more reasonable looking answers. I will check through all the data and then document and close if it is indeed correct. (I promise I looked at this for several hours before posting.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a little hard to test with only the four rows that you've provided. I created random data to see if it works and it seems to work for me. Try it on you data too.

This uses the `data.table` library and doesn't try to run `loops` inside a `ddply`. I'm assuming the means aren't important.

```
library(data.table)
dt <- data.table(df)  
l <- c(200)

# subsetting to keep only the important fields
dt <- dt[,list(session_id, Sentence_ID, CI, CI_Delta)]

# Initialising First_Pass    
dt[,First_Pass := 'F']

# The next two lines are basically rewording your logic -

# Within each group of session_id, Sentence_ID, identify the duplicate CI entries. These would have been inserted in l. The first time occurence of these CI entries is marked false as they wouldn't have been in l when that row was being checked 
dt[CI_Delta >= 0,duplicatedCI := duplicated(CI), by = c("session_id", "Sentence_ID")]

# So if the CI value hasn't occurred before within the session_id,Sentence_ID group, and it doesn't appear in l, then mark it as "T"
dt[!(CI %in% l) & !(duplicatedCI), First_Pass := "T"]

# Just for curiosity's sake, calculating l too
l <- c(l,dt[duplicatedCI == FALSE,CI])
```